# Toggle navigation with two classes

Tags: jquery

How can I build toggle li
element with class + or - on toggle, and sub-menu is display and not display.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sub-menu").hide();
  $(".sub-menu").parent('li').addClass('active');
  $(".sub-menu").parent('li').click(function() {
    $(".sub-menu").toggle("slow", function() {
      if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        $(".sub-menu").parent('li').addClass('unactive');
      } else {
        $(".sub-menu").parent('li').addClass('active');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.active::before {
  content: '+';
}

.noactive::before {
  content: '-';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li>Item2a</li>
      <li>Item2b</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is question?

Comment: + and - isn't work

Comment: 1. Provide the whole code, not a small piece. 2. Explain what you mean by "isn't work": What you do? What you expect to see? What is see actually?

Comment: I have a sub menu in primary, and on li element witch exist + on click show and hide sub menu. - is for hide sub menu, and that's not work (i don't see - in li, not change).

Comment: Provide your code so that we can see what is "sub-menu", what you have in "li", etc.

Comment: Note that every time you do `$(".sub-menu")`, your code scans the entirety of the DOM for those elements. I recommend storing it as a variable in the beginning and avoiding the excessive repeated lookups.

Comment: @showdev - That edit seems slightly misleading, no? As far as I can tell, OP never provided HTML. Not to mention that this HTML doesn't match the code.

Comment: @TylerRoper The OP provided HTML in a comment that has since been removed. I should have mentioned that in my edit comment. I did add the jQuery library, since the code seemed to required it. The edit should be rolled back if deemed misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you had a typo in class naming, but it doesn't resolve the problem, since the last css class is stronger, once it gets assigned it doesn't change on the next click. Try to use span element instead of classes here:

```
<ul>
<li>Item1</li>
<li><span>+</span>Item2
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Item2a</li>
        <li>Item2b</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And then you can use the .text() function to change its value on click :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".sub-menu").hide();

    $(".sub-menu").parent('li').click(function() {
        $(".sub-menu").toggle("slow", function() {
            if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
                $("span").text('-');
            } else {
                $("span").text('+');
            }
        });
    });
});
```